# Can you help me create a loop in VBA that will transpose data and put it in specific columns?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, transpose

In the dataset, I'm looking to put the members under each senior in a transposed version, with the senior's name as headers and all found members under that senior's column. I would like this to be dynamic because I'm getting these results after using an advanced filter. I have tried creating my loop but it's not yet dynamic. I'm pretty new to VBA and coding, so would like to tap on your expertise.

My current code looks like below where:

- CU is the senior column in the advanced filter result
- CI is the member column in the advanced filter result

Thank you so much!!!

```
StartRow = 6
StartCol = 5
UnderLevel2 = .Range("CI9999").End(xlUp).Row

For Member = 2 To UnderLevel2 'Row

    If ws.Cells(4, StartCol).Value = .Range("CU" & Member).Value Then
    ws.Cells(StartRow, StartCol).Value = .Range("CI" & Member).Value
    End If
    
    If ws.Cells(4, StartCol + 2).Value = .Range("CU" & Member).Value Then
    ws.Cells(StartRow, StartCol + 2).Value = .Range("CI" & Member).Value
    End If

    If ws.Cells(4, StartCol + 4).Value = .Range("CU" & Member).Value Then
    ws.Cells(StartRow, StartCol + 4).Value = .Range("CI" & Member).Value
    End If
    
    StartRow = StartRow + 2

Next Member
```

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCfAZ.jpg)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmscO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that SO is not a code writing service so edit your question, insert your code in the question and explain what is not working with your code.

Comment: If you post your code with a suitable definition of the error and what you expect then there may be many helping hands.

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question. Instead, include the relevant part of your code directly in the question.

Comment: You probably need:  [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial)

Comment: You could do this with formulas as well, if the amount of seniors doesn't change too often. Are you using Excel 365? If interested, I could provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) with the Senior as the key and the value as a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) of members.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub mymacro()

    Const StartRow = 6
    Const StartCol = 5
    Const COL_MEMBER = "A" ' "CU" ?
    Const COL_SENIOR = "B" ' "CI" ?
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim member As String, senior As String
    Dim underlevel2 As Long, r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    
    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' fill dictionary and collections from data sheet
    ' key = senior , value = collecton of members
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    With ws
        underlevel2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_SENIOR).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For r = 2 To underlevel2 'Row
        
            member = Trim(.Cells(r, COL_MEMBER))
            senior = Trim(.Cells(r, COL_SENIOR))
            If Not dict.exists(senior) Then
                dict.Add senior, New Collection
            End If
            dict(senior).Add member, CStr(r)
            
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox r - 1 & " members : " & dict.Count & " seniors", vbInformation
    
    ' output results
    c = StartCol
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(2)
    With wsOut
        .Cells.Clear
        For Each key In dict.keys
            r = StartRow - 2
            With .Cells(r, c)
               .Value = key ' senior
               .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
               .Borders.Weight = xlMedium
               .Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End With
            For n = 1 To dict(key).Count
                r = r + 2
                With .Cells(r, c)
                    .Value = dict(key).Item(n) ' senior
                    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders.Weight = xlMedium
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(1242, 161, 106)
               End With
            Next
            c = c + 2
        Next
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This code worked for my case. Thank you so much!